# Can we classify all spaces which go by the given below problem

Tags: general-topology

In chat I was discussing this problem which I thought of while doing my revision:

If $M$ is a subspace of the space $X$ and we have a mapping of $M$ from the space $Y$ can I extend this map to a mapping from the space $X$ to the space $Y$ .                  $\cdots (1)$

I was told that this is not true in general. Also by Tietze extension theorem it is true for closed subsets of $\Bbb R$ .

So my question is that can we classify all the spaces for which $(1)$ is true. By classify I mean to say that all the spaces which follow $(1)$ have a certain property in common(except being a topological space)

Answer (score 2):

For this a special relation between $X$ and $M$ is needed: $M$ must be a retract of $X$.

That means that a continuous map $r:X\rightarrow M$ must exist with $r\circ i=1_M$ where $i:M\rightarrow X$ denotes the inclusion of $M$.

Then any map $f:M\rightarrow Y$ induces a map $g=f\circ r: X\rightarrow Y$ such that the restriction of $g$ onto $M$  coincides with $f$. This because  $g\circ i=f\circ r\circ i=f$. This shows sufficiency.

Conversely if any continuous map $f$ on $M$ can be extended to a map on $X$, then also $1_M:M\rightarrow M$ can be extended. If $r:X\rightarrow M$ denotes this extension then $r\circ i=1_M$. This shows necessity.

So it comes to a classification of pairs $(X,M)$ and not just of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If by *a map* you understand a continuous function then the answer is no. Indeed, take $M=(0,\infty)$ and let $$f(x) = 1/x\quad(x\in M).$$ Then $f$ admits no continuous extension to $[0,\infty)$.

However, if you assume that $X$ is a metric space and $f$ is uniformly continuous, then it can be continuously extended to the closure of $M$ and hence, by Tietze's theorem, to the whole $X$.